# AWS S3 Bucket Policy - Only Allow Certain File Types In Folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-access-policy

I have a specific folder in my bucket that I would like to restrict to only certain file types.  I currently have the following:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1464968545158",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1464968483619",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/my-folder/*"
            ]
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                  "s3:prefix": ".txt",
                  "s3:prefix": ".doc"
                }
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

I need something to replace `s3:prefix` so that instead of looking at the beginning of the file and path, the system is looking at the end.  I tried `s3:suffix`, but this isn't a valid property.

Is there a S3 property that does a wildcard search at the end of the file name so I can whitelist only certain file types for my folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to define it in the `Resource` using wildcard. Use `Effect: Allow` if you want folder to be restricted to `.txt` and `.doc` only.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1464968545158",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1464968483619",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/my-folder/*.doc",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/my-folder/*.txt"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The same way as Deny Effect is used you can use allow effect. Both the examples are as below:

Allow only specific ones and deny specific ones if needed....

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "Policy1464968545158",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1464968483619",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "IAM-USER-ARN"
      },
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*.doc",
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*.txt"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1464968483619",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "NotResource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*.png",
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*.gif"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```